# Theoretical justification of choice for confidence interval exact method for the success probability parameter of negative binomial variable?

Tags: distributions, confidence-interval, binomial-distribution, negative-binomial-distribution

I have a computer experiment that runs the Bernoulli series with unknown probability $p$ of success. The experiment terminates when $m$ failures are observed. So, the unknown parameter $p$ has the unbiased estimation $\frac{m}{r+m}$, where $r$ is a number of observed successes before $m$-th failure occurs. In another words, $r$ is a sample of a negative binomial variable $N \sim BI(m,p)$.

Now I want to launch $s$ copies of this experiment on $s$ computers independently (technically, it means a unique seed for a separate random generator). The estimation is  $\frac{s \cdot m}{\sum_i (r_i+m)}$ now, where $r_i$ is a sample of $N \sim BI(m,p)$. Here starts the main question, what exact approach below gives me the tightest confidence interval of desired confidence level $\alpha$ for probability parameter $p$?

- Compute the CI of parameter $p$ as the intersection of $s$ Clopper-Pearson CIs of confidence level $\sqrt[s]{\alpha}$ computed for $s$ samples $r_i$ of the variable $N \sim BI(m,p)$
- Compute the CI of parameter $p$ for variable $\tilde{N} \sim BI(s \cdot m, p)$ from a single sample $\sum_i r_i$ by Clopper-Pearson exact method

I am interested in theoretical justification.

Below you can find my Mathematica code of methods above.

```
ClopperPearsonCI[n_, {m_, level_}] :=
 Block[{F},
  F[x_, pr_] = CDF[NegativeBinomialDistribution[m, pr], x];
  Interval[
   {
    pr /. 
     Last@NMinimize[{(F[n - m, pr] - (1 - level)/2)^2, 0 <= pr <= 1}, pr],
    pr /. 
     Last@NMinimize[{(1 - F[n - m - 1, pr] - (1 - level)/2)^2, 0 <= pr <= 1}, pr]
    }
   ]
  ];

MethodA[samples_, {m_, a_}] :=
 IntervalIntersection @@
  Map[
   ClopperPearsonCI[#, {m, a^(1/Length[samples])}]&,
   samples
  ];

MethodB[samples_, {m_, a_}] := ClopperPearsonCI[Total[samples], {m*s, a}];
```

By the way, the empirical justification shows me that the second approach is preferable.

Comment: Bit odd to compare approximate vs exact CIs simply according to which gives a *tighter* interval. Because the distribution's discrete there are some methods to improve on (two-sided) Clopper-Pearson intervals while maintaining exact coverage by a bit of jiggling, but whether you like the results of any of them depends on what other properties of confidence intervals you think it important to conserve (e.g. nesting of CIs with less coverage inside ones with more coverage).

Comment: @Scortchi Let me fix the confidence level $\alpha$ and the probability $p$ of success. Assume we have $N$ model datasets $D_i = \{d_{i,j}\}$ of length $s$ those are sampled from negative binomial distribution with known parameters $p$ and $m$. CI is wanted to contain the probability parameter $p$ for at least $\alpha \cdot N$ datasets. I do an experiment with $m=20, p=0.3, N=10^4, s=5, \alpha=0.95$ and observed that the covering probabilities are $0.95$ and $0.96$ correspondingly for methods from my question. So it's ok if a method uses some approximation of the negative binomial distribution.

Comment: @Scortchi I have fixed my question to compare only between exact methods.